# Шаблонный метод в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонный класс с двумя параметрами, один из которых типа int (размер массива). Необходимо в этом классе реализовать метод, который принимает этот же класс, но возможно что с другим значением параметра шаблона.
Пример того как я сделал:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T, int Size = 10>
class Arr
{
public:
    Arr() {
        real = 0;
        buff = Size;
    }

    template<int N>
    void merge(Arr<T, N>& arr) {
        cout << "Everything is OK!" << arr.getSize();
    }

    int getSize() {
        return Size;
    }

private:
    int buff;
    int real;
};

int main()
{
    Arr<int, 5> arr1;
    Arr<int, 500> arr2;
    arr1.merge(arr2);

    return 0;
}
```

Верно ли так делать? И если верно, то как синтаксически верно вынести определение метода вне определения класса?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Abyx Не бессмысленно. В стандартной библиотеке это делается на регулярной основе. Реализация метода выносится не только за пределы класса, но и за пределы файла - чтобы не мешалась. А в конце заголовочного файла в него обычным `#include`'ом включается файл с реализациями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу ничего криминального в вашем коде.

Я бы вынес метод из класса так:

```
template<typename T, int Size>
template<int N>
void Arr<T, Size>::merge(Arr<T, N>& arr) {
    cout << "Everything is OK!" << arr.getSize();
}
```

([проверка](http://ideone.com/oQUJSa))

Однако, не забывайте, что реализация шаблонов всё равно должна быть в header-файле, иначе вы [получите проблемы при линковке](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl).Поэтому вынесение метода из шаблона много не даст.

Answer (score 1):

Непосредственно на сам вопрос уже дан исчерпывающий ответ. Поэтому я буду говорить о другом. В дизайне класса есть одна проблема, которая на первый взгляд не видна. Метод `merge` возвращает `void`, что подразумевает объединение двух массивов внутри первого. И это не соответствует оптимистичной формуле "Everything is OK!". Отнюдь не OK... По крайней мере, не Everything. Дело в том, что результатом объединения `Arr<int, 5>` с `Arr<int, 500>`, по замыслу должно стать значение с типом `Arr<int, 505>`. Но этого не будет. Тип первого массива, внутри которого происходит объединение, останется `Arr<int, 5>`. В результате есть вероятность того, что следующее объединение того же массива с ещё одним произойдёт неправильно: в объединении будут участвовать только первые 5 элементов.

Конечно, можно реализовать объединение таким образом, что оно не будет учитывать размер массива из типа, но это методологически неверно. Лучше объявить метод следующим образом.

```
template<int N>
Arr<T, Size+N> merge(Arr<T, N>& arr);
```

И, соответственно, объединение делать не внутри первого массива, а в новом массиве.

Если же хочется объединять именно внутри первого, то его тип изначально должен иметь такой `Size`, который позволит вместить содержимое второго массива. Это обязательно нужно будет проверять перед объединением. Кроме того, это, очевидно, изменит семантику параметра `Size`. Правильнее будет назвать его `Capacity`.

Ну, а чтобы всё вообще было тип-топ, хорошо бы ещё добавить в класс шаблонный оператор `+` (или `+=` в случае объединения на месте), а также свободный оператор `+`, объединяющий два массива любого размера.

```
template<typename T, int Size1, int Size2>
Arr<T, Size1+Size2> operator +(Arr<T, Size1>& arr1, Arr<T, Size2>& arr2) {
    cout << "Cool kids love free operators!" << arr1.getSize()+arr2.getSize() << endl;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx Внимательнее читайте вопрос в следующий раз :)

Comment: @Abyx Вопрос был задан максимально широко: верно ли так делать?

Comment: @Abyx А вы, видимо, не заметили, что в массив размером 5 вмерживается массив размером 500. Но ничего страшного. Это такой пустяк на фоне "ценнейшего" совета оформить мой ответ в виде комментария :)

Comment: @Abyx Ах, ну да, простите... Про SmallVector - это, конечно, не ваши догадки и домыслы. Автор в своём вопросе чётко говорит о том, что пытается реализовать аналог SmallVector. Я, к сожалению, сразу этого не заметил :)